# Classic ASP sliding expiration

Tags: asp-classic, iis-6

Just a query;
Is the classic ASP do have sliding expiration like forms auth in asp.net?

Comment: What are you using for authentication in Classic ASP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such thing as a property to expire form based authentication in classic asp.

Authentication in classic asp can be roughly divided in windows challenge/response and form-based authentication (often in combination with a database-driven username /password).
You could use the session expiration as an alternative (for instance if the form-based authentication sets a a session value "isAuthenticated"). The default session timeout is 20 minutes, but this can be easily altered by adjusting Session.Timeout